# QGIS 2.2 expression string builder removes brackets

Tags: qgis, string, expression

in QGIS 2.0.1 is used to calculate minimum building distances (Abstandsflächen in German) with an ellipse marker with data definded properties. the expression for this is quite complex:

```
(([Value 1] + [Value 2] / '2' * '1,01' * '0,464' )* '0,25' + sqrt([Value 3] ^ 2 + ([Value 2] / '2' * 1.01) ^ 2))*2
```

When I do the exact same thing in QGIS 2.2, the expression string builder changes the expression when saving it into this:

```
Nabenhoehe + Rotor / '2' * '1,01' * '0,464' * '0,25' + sqrt("Nabe Turm" ^ 2 + Rotor / '2' * 1.01 ^ 2) * '2'
```

As you can see, the brackets are removed, therefore the result of the calculation is wrong.
I have no idea why this works in QGIS 2.0.1, but doesn't in QGIS 2.2 ...

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it was a bug in 2.2.  It has been fixed for the next release.

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9783